# Understanding MVT in several variables

Tags: calculus

I am attempting to understand the proof of MVT for multivariable functions as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables), but it seems like I need a more simple explanation (if there is one). 
For example, let us consider $z = f(x, y)$ - the function of two variables.
To start with, we fix two points: $a, b$ of the function domain - ($x_1, y_1$) for point $a$ and ($x_2, y_2$) for point $b$. 
Next, we define function $g(t) = f((1 - t)a + tb)$ 
First question:
Does function $g(t)$ imply computing $f((1-t)x_1+tx_2, (1-t)y_1+ty_2)$ ? 
Second question: how to compute explicitly $g'(c)$ so that we get $\nabla f((1-c)x+cy)\cdot (y-x)$ according to the link above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: yes, it is exactly what you thought it means.

Second quesion:

$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial{[(1-t)x_1+tx_2]}}*\frac{d[(1-t)x_1+tx_2]}{dt}+ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial[(1-t)y_1+ty_2]}*\frac{d[(1-t)y_1+ty_2]}{dt}$$

The above expression is a dot product of the gradient of $f$ evaluated on the line $\nabla f((1-t)a+tb)$ dot with the vector $\frac{d[(1-t)a+tb]}{dt}=b-a$

$$g'(t)=\nabla{f((1-t)a+tb)}*(b-a)$$